# Mongo/Monk count of objects in collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I'm 2 hours into Mongo/Monk with node.js and I want to count how many objects I have inserted into a collection but I can't see any docs on how to do this with Monk.

Using the below doesn't seem to return what I expect

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/mydb');
var collection = db.get('tweets');
collection.count()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a query and a callback. `.count()` is asynchronous and will just return a promise, not the actual document count value.

```
collection.count({}, function (error, count) {
  console.log(error, count);
});
```

Comment: `var collectionCount = 0;

collection.count({}, function (error, count) {
    console.log(error, count);
    collectionCount = count; // lets say count is 10
    console.log(collectionCount); // 10
  });
console.log(collectionCount); // 0
`
How to use it outside collection count?

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use [co-monk](http://npmjs.org/package/co-monk) and take the rest of the morning off:

```
var monk = require('monk');
var wrap = require('co-monk');
var db = monk('localhost/test');
var users = wrap(db.get('users'));
var numberOfUsers = yield users.count({});
```

Of course that requires that you stop doing callbacks... :)